# Как сделать правильную выборку характеристик товара с помощью Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Нужно получить результат для каждого товара в виде

```php
$product->features = [
   [
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'Weight'
      'values' => [
          ['value' => 10],
          ['value' => 15]
       ]
   ],
   ...
];
```

На данный момент получить такой результат я смог с помощью данного кода.

```php
$products = Product::whereIsActive(true)->with([
            'brand',
            'categories',
            'values.feature'
        ])->get([
            'id',
            'name',
            'brand_id'
            ])->map(function($p, $key) {

            foreach ($p->values as $v) {
                if (! array_key_exists($v->feature->id, $p->features)) {
                    $p->features[$v->feature->id]['data'] = $v->feature;
                }

                $p->features[$v->feature->id]['values'][] = $v;
            }

            return $p;
        });
```

Изначально после выборки результат такой

```
{
 features => [],
 values => [
   0 => [
     'value' => 5,
     'feature' => [
       'id' => '1'    
       'name' => 'Weight'
     ]
   ],
   1 => [
     'value' => 5,
     'feature' => [
       'id' => '1'    
       'name' => 'Weight'
     ]
   ]
  ],
}
```

После выполнения `map()`

```
{
 features => [
  1 => [
    id => 1,
    name => 'Weight',
    values => [
    0 => [
     'value' => 5,
     'feature' => [
       'id' => '1'    
       'name' => 'Weight'
     ]
   ],
   1 => [
     'value' => 5,
     'feature' => [
       'id' => '1'    
       'name' => 'Weight'
     ]
   ]
  ]
 ],
 values => [
   0 => [
     'value' => 5,
     'feature' => [
       'id' => '1'    
       'name' => 'Weight'
     ]
   ],
   1 => [
     'value' => 5,
     'feature' => [
       'id' => '1'    
       'name' => 'Weight'
     ]
   ]
  ],
}
```

Но, проблема в том, что, для этого нужно создать в модели `Product` доп. публичное свойство `features` и записывать результат перебора в него.
Есть ли другой, более правильный и простой вариант решения данной задачи?

**products**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | is_active | name      |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 | Flower red|
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public $features = [];

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            FeatureValue::class,
            'feature_product',
            'product_id',
            'value_id',
            'id'
        )->withPivot('product_id','feature_id', 'value_id');
    }
}
```

**features** и **feature_values**

```
+----+--------+          +----+------------+-------+
| id | name   |          | id | feature_id | value |
+----+--------+          +----+------------+-------+
|  1 | Weight |          |  1 |          1 | 3     |
+----+--------+          |  2 |          1 | 5     |
                         +----+------------+-------+
```

```php
class Feature extends Model
{
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FeatureValue::class)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }

}
```

```php
class FeatureValue extends Model
{
    public function feature()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Feature::class);
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Product::class,
            'feature_product',
            'product_id'
        );
    }
}
```

pivot **feature_product**

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| feature_id | product_id | value_id |
+------------+------------+----------+
|          1 |          1 |        1 |
|          1 |          1 |        2 |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Я бы избавился от модели/таблицы `FeatureValue`, а значения хранил бы в `pivot feature_product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете в модели Products описать нужный Вам атрибут.

```
public function getFeaturesAttribute() {
 // описание выборки аттрибута
}
```

И этот метод будет выполняться, когда будет обращение к $product->features